# Android Studio 2.3.1 Ubuntu 17.04 Unity 8 problem: Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment

Tags: unity, android, android-studio, unity8

I've just recently installed  Ubuntu 17.04. Also, I installed Android Studio in the default desktop and it works fine, but when I switch to Unity 8 and then try to launch Android Studio I get this message:

```
$ cd /usr/local/android-studio/bin/
$ ./studio.sh 
Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

Comment: same issue i faced